# ffmpeg ios, decoding rtsp stream causes memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, ffmpeg, rtsp

i have an ios application that stream a rtsp video via network using ffmpeg library.
In random time i have a crash without error message, the only message in console is "Memory warning".
Using instrument i detect some memory leaks, this link a screenshot about error: http://vincentvega.it/iphone/video.png, i think the problem is in the point of code where i make uiimage to show on screen:

```
- (void)convertFrameToRGB
{
    sws_scale(img_convert_ctx,
              pFrame->data,
              pFrame->linesize,
              0,
              pCodecCtx->height,
              picture.data,
              picture.linesize);

}

- (UIImage *)imageFromAVPicture:(AVPicture)pict width:(int)width height:(int)height
{
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CFDataRef data = CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, pict.data[0], pict.linesize[0]*height,kCFAllocatorNull);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate(width, 
                                       height, 
                                       8, 
                                       24, 
                                       pict.linesize[0], 
                                       colorSpace, 
                                       bitmapInfo, 
                                       provider, 
                                       NULL, 
                                       NO, 
                                       kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];



    return [image autorelease];
}
```

how can i detect the function that causes memory problem?

SOLVED! I just neeed to add the following code in "imagefromavcapture":

```
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CFRelease(data);
```